# Redirect to login page in asp.net core idenity in ViewComponent

Tags: asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-viewcomponent, razor-class-library

I am trying to make my viewcomponent accessible only if user is logged in. I am checking if user is not authenticated then redirect to login page but following code is giving me error

```
public IViewComponentResult Invoke(int? id)
        {

            if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {   
                return View("~/Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/Login.cshtml");
            }
//other stuff
}
```

but this code is giving me error on login page

```
ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: viewData
```

On Checking loginviewmodel it has overloaded constructor only that takes arguments

```
public LoginModel(SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager, ILogger<LoginModel> logger)
```

I can't figure out how to send these aruguments. Or there is a better way to redirect to login page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View components aren't part of the authorization pipeline. They're part of the view rendering pipeline, and by that point, it's too late to deny access or redirect. If the view component should not display if the user isn't logged in, then simply return an empty result, i.e. `return Content(string.Empty);`. Alternatively, you can gate it in your view:

```
@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    @await Component.InvokeAsync("MyComponent")
}
```

The last part of your question is I think a complete misunderstanding of how things work here. A view component is just a way of rendering a partial while doing some sort of additional work a partial can't or shouldn't handle directly, such as injecting dependencies, querying a database, etc. Here, you're trying to return a Razor Page, which is *not* a partial. Razor Pages only work when directly routed to. The dependencies that you can't figure out how to satisfy are satisfied by the framework during the instantiating of the page model after routing.

Answer (score 0):

Did you read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/overview?view=aspnetcore-2.2

When you use `return View()` ASP.net looks in to the `Views` folder for a folder named after your controller, and for a view named after the method. So when you use `return View()` in the method Profile of the AccountController, asp.net looks for a view in Views/Account/Profile.cshtml.

The view method optionally accepts a parameter. Here you need to pass a viewmodel (the data you want to display in the view)

Furthermore, if you want to authorize access to a controller method, you should use role-based or claim-based authorization: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-2.2